# 3D plotting in R with categorical data

Tags: r, 3d, plot, categorical-data

So I am fairly new to the whole 3D plotting in R thing, and have spent the last day reading up various articles and posts in here and other websites/books. And I have to confess, I am still lost. So any help/advice people can give me will be hugely appreciated!

Ok, so here is my issue (with example data). I have 3 Locations (A-C) sampled for 12 consecutive years (2001-2012) for some measure, with many zeros. So I have this data in a table/matrix/dataframe:

```
LocationA<-c(0,0,0.83,0.167,0.167,0.083,0.25,0.212,0,0.083,0,0)
LocationB<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.212,0,0)
LocationC<-c(0.633,0.462,0.167,0.467,0,0.167,0.451,0.333,0.462,0.595,0,0)

TestMat<-cbind(LocationA,LocationB,LocationC)
rownames(TestMat)<-c(2001:2012)
```

What I would like would be similar to a topographical map, with the x-axis being the Location, z-axis the Year, and y-axis the value of the thing I am measuring. I would be potentially open to using bar-plots, but ideally something like wireframe() would be best. I have been messing around with various functions and packages, but I cant quite figure out why what I am doing is not working.

Thank you very much for your help! I am fully aware that I may just be a bit of an idiot and not getting it, so thank you for bearing with me!

Cheers!

EDIT:

So I changed it to a "long-read". The x-values couldnt be non-numeric, so I changed them to x2 (as shown below).

```
x<-c(rep("LocationA",12),rep("LocationB",12),rep("LocationC",12))
y<-rep(c(2001:2012),3)
z<-c(LocationA,LocationB,LocationC)
x2<-c(rep(1,12),rep(2,12),rep(3,12))
```

I then used the wireframe() function:

```
wireframe(z~x2*y,xlab="Location",ylab="Year",zlab="Value",distance=0.4,zoom=0.6,
        scales=list(arrows=FALSE,
                x=list(at=c(1:3),label=c("A","B","C")),
                y=list(at=c(2001:2012),label=c(2001:2012)),
            z=list(at=c(0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1),label=c(0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1)),
                distance=c(2,2,2)),
        drape=TRUE)
```

Now, the thing I cannot figure out, and have been fiddling with, is the colouring. I know that the drape() sub-function allows me to give the lattice a gradient of colour changes, with the higher values showing a different colour to the lower ones. However, I cannot seem to get it to work. It does give me a colour gradation, but the highest value (in this is 0.83) which should be a turquoise colour (the default colour gradient is pink-turquoise - will attempt to change this later), is in fact the colour corresponding to ~0.3 value. There is no error message or warning message attached, and I have no idea why this is happening... Any ideas?

Thanks again! :)

Comment: Perhaps, it would be helpful to have your "data.frame" in a long format; i.e. 3 columns [ "x" = loc, "y" = year, "z" = value ] and try different "lattice" stuff like `contourplot(z ~ x * y)` or `wireframe(z ~ x * y)`

Comment: Ok cool, so the wireframe(z~x*y) kinda works, provided I reclassify LocA etc as numeric (i.e. 1,2,3 etc). Now I just will figure out how to annotate the plot, but otherwise I think I can work it out from here. Thanks! :)

Comment: I don't post in reference to your specific problem; more for a suggestion/opinion. As an anternative to a 3D `wireframe` you could try something like `tmp = as.data.frame(as.table(TestMat)); levelplot(Freq ~ Var1 * Var2, tmp, col.regions = terrain.colors(100))` (if you don't specify "col.regions" you'll get the pink-to-blue default coloring; "col.regions" works for manipulating `wireframe`'s coloring, too). Hope any of this helps.